# Interfaces that can use generics with generics (interface Example<T<?>>)

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface, modeling

It seems I am trying to do the modeling of something that might not be possible in csharp syntax wise. I hope somebody can prove me wrong.

I would like to have an interface that can have a generic type of "T<?>", such as:

```cs
interface MyExample<T<?>> {
  ...
}
```

So I could have my interface defining few properties where their types will be a T. My intention is that this interface will define the name of some properties, but not their exact return types (just a portion of it, so I can control the return types through inheritance).

So by having other interfaces inheriting from it, I could define what are the properties real return values for each interface. Take a look on the example below:

```cs
interface MyConfigs<T<>> { // this <T<>> throws error
  T<CustomerConfig> Customer { get; }
  T<SupplierConfig> Supplier { get; }
}

interface Mocks : MyConfigs<Mock> {}
interface Providers : MyConfigs<Provider> {}

class Mock<T> {
  void Setup() => ...
}

class Provider<T> {
   T Get() => ...
}
```

In the example above I try to create two interfaces "Mocks" and "Providers", which would have exactly the same property names, but their return types would be different. However, since I don't know how I can make my "MyConfigs" accept a "generics that have generics" as T, I am not being able to do the desired modeling.

If anyone knows how this could be achieved, it would be amazing for my studies!

Thank you

Comment: What is your actual requirement? Can you briefly explain why you think this is the way to go?

Comment: I would like to have an interface that would define how many properties needs to be implemented by other interfaces. So as soon as there is a new property added to it, it requires the other places to implement it as well. However, while in one place this new property could be a "string", in others it could be list<string>, and in others a Mock<string>

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve the desired effect by creating an interface with N generic types. Each generic type can define the expected return type of a property in the interface.

Check the example below:

```cs
interface MyProperties<TName, TAge, TIsActive> {
   TName Name { get; }
   TAge Age { get; }
   TIsActive IsActive { get; }
}

interface MyValues : MyProperties<string, int, bool> {

}

interface MyMocks : MyProperties<Mock<string>, Mock<int>, Mock<bool>> {

}

interface MyLists : MyProperties<List<string>, List<int>, List<bool>> {

}
```

So I was able to define the interface "MyProperties" that would specify what are the three desired properties, but leave their value open to be defined by other interfaces/classes.

So the interfaces "MyValues", "MyMocks", "MyLists" all have the same three properties but just different return types.